# Excel 2010 VBA code to reference multiple cells from one worksheet into the summary workshet

Tags: vba, reference, cell

I have a huge spreadsheet that contains a "Summary" worksheet, which has a row for each worksheet in the spreadsheet.  All of the worksheets (except the master and template) are named based on the value in Column D (Person's last name).

I want to run a macro that will reference the following cells but in reverse.  (I want to reference the cells from the specific sheet to the dSht)

Here is the coding I have going one way.

I can't figure out how to make it go the other way for the specific row selected.  (Say I have row 150 selected, the value in Column D is the name of the worksheet, and I want to reference the cells from that worksheet in columns located in the dSht.

But I don't want the value to be pasted I want that cell to be referenced so if I update it on the specific page it updates on the Summary page.  Currently I'm just manually typing =LastName!E3 for each cell / column.

Dim LastRw As Long, Rw As Long, Cnt As Long
    Dim dSht As Worksheet, tSht As Worksheet
    Dim MakeBooks As Boolean, SavePath As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'speed up macro execution
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'no alerts, default answers used

```
Set dSht = Sheets("All Accidents & Incidents") 'sheet with data on it starting in row2
Set tSht = Sheets("Template") 'sheet to copy and fill out
```

'   Determine last row of data then loop through the rows one at a time

```
LastRw = dSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
tSht.Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) 'copy the template
With ActiveSheet 'fill out the form
```

'       edit these rows to fill out your form, add more as needed

```
    ' Case Number
    .Range("E3").Value = dSht.Range("N" & LastRw).Value
    ' case #
    .Range("E4").Value = dSht.Range("P" & LastRw).Value
    'Case #
    .Range("E5").Value = dSht.Range("R" & LastRw).Value
    'Case #
    .Range("E6").Value = dSht.Range("T" & LastRw).Value
    'Case #
    .Range("E7").Value = dSht.Range("V" & LastRw).Value

    'Pmts
    .Range("H27").Value = dSht.Range("X" & LastRw).Value
    ' Pmts
    .Range("H38").Value = dSht.Range("Y" & LastRw).Value
    ' Pmts
    .Range("H46").Value = dSht.Range("Z" & LastRw).Value
    'Billback
    .Range("H16").Value = dSht.Range("AA" & LastRw).Value
    'Company Pmts
    .Range("H65").Value = dSht.Range("AB" & LastRw).Value
     'Net Loss
    .Range("H77").Value = dSht.Range("AC" & LastRw).Value
    'Total Cost
    .Range("H78").Value = dSht.Range("AD" & LastRw).Value

    'Description
    .Range("A81").Value = dSht.Range("AM" & LastRw).Value


    ActiveSheet.Name = .Range("I3").Value
```